# How to recover phone from lost mi account?

Tags: xiaomi

I got a xiaomi mi4i from my brother a while ago which was lying with him for quite a while. So, after I got it, I did a factory reset and tried logging into mi account only to realize that the device has been associated with another account. I asked my brother about account info but he had given the phone to a friend and he doesn't remember the account. So, basically the phone is useless right now.

BTW, before anyone of you say so, this phone is not stolen and I have the proof of purchase with me.

So, is there anything I can do to remove the associated mi account?

I know I can downgrade the OS to unlock it, but as soon as I upgrade from it, it again locks the phone with a message "this device is locked". what can I do to unlock it?

Comment: A rapid Google search shows tons of potential solutions to your problem! This one for example: http://en.miui.com/thread-428375-1-1.html

Comment: @esQmo_ I know. As I've mentioned in the question(read the last paragraph). I tried calling the call centre and they suggested I go to the service centre. To which they say, they have to change the motherboard and they can't fix it through software. So basically I have 130g of paper weight. That's why I'm looking for an unofficial hack to bypass the mi account login.

Comment: There are tools that can reset the lock via fastboot. Just Google for that

Comment: Or just downgrad and use it like that